# ionic 3 in-app-browser get click event in app

Tags: ionic-framework

ionic 3 in-app-browser get click event in ionic app
Hear is my code

```
  let target = "_blank";
  const browser = this.iab.create(url,target,this.options);
  browser.on('loadstop').subscribe(event => {
  browser.executeScript({code: `$("[data-menu=logout]").attr('data-menu','logout_custom');
    $("[data-menu=logout_custom]").attr('href',url);
    $("[data-menu=logout_custom]").on('click',function(){
      webkit.messageHandlers.cordova_iab.postMessage('REACT_EXIT');
      this.backendMessage('REACT_EXIT')
    })
  `});
});
```

this.backendMessage('REACT_EXIT')   this function is in my ionic app
I need to call this function on click of logout_custom

Comment: Use addeventlistner and when function is emited from browser it will listen to it and give you what you want to achieve

Comment: @MostafaHarb thank you for replay

Can you give me an example of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
let target = "_blank";
    const browser = this.iab.create(url,target,this.options);
    browser.on('loadstop').subscribe(event => {
      console.log(event,"loadstop");
      browser.executeScript({code: $("[data-menu=logout]").attr('data-menu','logout_custom');
        $("[data-menu=logout_custom]").click(function(){
          var message = 'REACT_EXIT';
          var messageObj = {my_message: message};
          var stringifiedMessageObj = JSON.stringify(messageObj);
          window.webkit.messageHandlers.cordova_iab.postMessage(stringifiedMessageObj);
        });}).then((cookie) =>{
        console.log(cookie,"cookie");
      }).catch((error)=>{
        console.log(error,"error");
      });
    });
    browser.on('message').subscribe((event) => {
      console.log('postmessage received',event);
      const postObject:any = event
      if(postObject.data.my_message == 'REACT_EXIT'){
         console.log(postObject.data.my_message);
      }
      console.log('other message');
    })
```

Comment: @Bhagirath Gadhesariya  Please do upvotes, it will be much appreciated!!